# Cannot use import statement outside a module in an electron.js with typescript react.js project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, import, electron

I'm getting this error:

```
(base) marco@pc01:~/webMatters/electronMatters/react-ggc$ yarn 
electron .
yarn run v1.22.5
warning ../package.json: No license field
$ /home/marco/webMatters/electronMatters/react-ggc/node_modules
/.bin/electron .
App threw an error during load
/home/marco/webMatters/electronMatters/react-ggc/src/main.ts:14
import * as logdown from 'logdown';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1051:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules
cjs/loader.js:1166:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:981:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:881:14)
    at Function.Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:769:28)
    at loadApplicationPackage (/home/marco/webMatters/electronMatters
/react-ggc/node_modules/electron/dist/resources/default_app.asar 
/main.js:109:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/marco/webMatters/electronMatters
/react-ggc/node_modules/electron/dist/resources/default_app.asar
/main.js:155:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1145:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules
/cjs/loader.js:1166:10)

A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
Uncaught Exception:
/home/marco/webMatters/electronMatters/react-ggc/src/main.ts:14
import * as logdown from 'logdown';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1051:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1166:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:981:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:881:14)
    at Function.Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:769:28)
    at loadApplicationPackage (/home/marco/webMatters/electronMatters/react-ggc/node_modules
/electron/dist/resources/default_app.asar/main.js:109:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/marco/webMatters/electronMatters/react-ggc/node_modules
/electron/dist/resources/default_app.asar/main.js:155:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1145:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1166:10)
```

Following the suggestions found here: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/1007
I've put in package.json:

```
"type": "module"
```

and this is tsconfig.json :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "es2017",
      "es2019",
      "dom",
      "webworker"
    ],
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "pretty": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

I already installed @types/node": "^12.0.0" and already put in /src
package.json :

```
{ "type": "module" }


node version: v14.5.0
Ubuntu 18.04.4 Desktop
electron: 10.1.2
```

How to solve the problem?
looking forward to your kind help